# Txt Editor or Office feature for interweaving the lines of multiple paragraphs. ie: musical or theatrical composition

Tags: text, libreoffice

Doable in Libre Office? Doesn't need to take solid paragaphs and interweave them.Just need to set it up so it does it as i type them.
 The problem with manually doing it is everytime you edit the text or change the font size it throws off the lines and you have to start all over again. I'm sure there is lots of applications, all i can think of is in music where people are singing different words at the same time or a play-script where multiple conversations are going on at once or if you wanted to put non verbal cues underneath.

Example:

```
Paragraph 1 Line 1 
Paragraph 2 Line 1
Paragraph 1 Line 2
Paragraph 2 Line 2
```

Editing:

```
Paragraph 1 Line 1 if this line get too long it skips the next line and....
Paragraph 2 Line 1
....puts goes here. Paragraph 1 Line 2
Paragraph 2 Line 2
```